# Spark Streaming with multiple Kafka streams

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-kafka

I create kafka stream with the following codes:

```
val streams = (1 to 5) map {i => 
    KafkaUtils.createStream[....](
              streamingContext,
              Map( .... ),
              Map(topic -> numOfPartitions),
              StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER
              ).filter(...)
              .mapPartitions(...)
              .reduceByKey(....)
val unifiedStream = streamingContext.union(streams)
unifiedStream.foreachRDD(...)
streamingContext.start()
```

I give each stream different group id. When I run the application, only part of kafka messages are received and the executor is pending at foreachRDD call. If I only create one stream, everything works well. There aren't any exceptions from logging info.

I don't know why the application is stuck there. Does it mean no enough resources?

Answer (score 0):

You want to try set the parameter

```
SparkConf().set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "5")
```